# AFNetworking response shows up in the log but is nil in the debugger

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to get a JSON response. I am getting is as a PhotoPXArray (model I created using mantle). The log output is exactly the data I want. My problem is using the data. When I set a break point and look at the responseObject, it is nil. I don't know why the log is pumping out data but the value is nil in the debugger.

What I am ultimately trying to do is save the response to use it later.

Also, I am using Sculptor to help with serializing.

```
-(NSArray*) getPhotoForWord:(NSString*)word {
    NSArray *results = nil;
    __block NSMutableDictionary *test = nil;

    NSString *requestString = BASE_URL;
    requestString = [requestString stringByAppendingString:@"photos/search?term="];
    requestString = [requestString stringByAppendingString:word];
    requestString = [requestString stringByAppendingString:CONSUMER_KEY];



    NSString *encoded = [requestString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [SCLMantleResponseSerializer serializerForModelClass:PhotoPXArray.class];
    [manager GET:encoded
      parameters:nil
         //success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
             test = responseObject;

         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }];


    return results;
}
```

Comment: If you call this function, it is likely that it will return a nil `results` right away, but the block will be called in a few second later since get data is an asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 1):

You never set `results` variable, so of course that will return `nil`. Even if you used `test` (which you do set), that happens asynchronously, so when you immediately return, it will be `nil`, too, only getting the `responseObject` value later.

You might consider employing an asynchronous pattern, instead, supplying a completion handler parameter:

```
- (void)getPhotoForWord:(NSString*)word completionHandler:(void (^)(id responseObject, NSError *error))completionHandler{
    NSString *requestString = BASE_URL;
    requestString = [requestString stringByAppendingString:@"photos/search?term="];
    requestString = [requestString stringByAppendingString:word];
    requestString = [requestString stringByAppendingString:CONSUMER_KEY];

    NSString *encoded = [requestString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [SCLMantleResponseSerializer serializerForModelClass:PhotoPXArray.class];
    [manager GET:encoded parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(responseObject, nil);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(nil, error);
        }
    }];
}
```

You'd then call that like so:

```
[obj getPhotoForWord:word completionHandler:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    // use responseObject here
}];

// do not use it here because the above happens asynchronously (i.e. later)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't assigning results to anything.  The only 2 times it appears in your code is when you declared it:
`NSArray *results = nil;`
and when you return it:
`return results;`

What it appears you are missing is parsing your `test` dictionary and populating an array, then returning that?

But as gabbler said in the comments, the call is asynchronous so unless you set up a semaphore, notifications, or something along those lines to make it synchronous, the return has a chance to be `nil` anyways.